# the size of sub node changes causing changes of parent node's size in javafx

Tags: javafx, imageview

For example, I use an imageview as the sub node of a vbox, when I change the size property(fitWidthProperty and fitHeightProperty), the size of box also changes. How can I stop this? There just do it like the code follows.But actually Vbox is the child of GridPane which I don't list it.

```
public int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 200;
//onAction means a click on button
public void onAction(){
   changeDefaultWidth();    
}
//initial another control ,just like pagination.
public void configureCellFactory(){
   VBox box = new VBox();
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
   imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(default_width);
   box.getChildren().add(imageView);
}
```

Comment: See if you can set the maxWidth and maxHeight of the parent node.

Comment: It doesn't work before I change the size of imageview.

Comment: Post code that produces your problem.

Comment: The size of the `VBox` is determined by its parent, and the layout settings you use on it and its parent. Post a [MCVE] explaining what how you want it to behave.

Comment: I just change the size of Imageview which as a child node of vbox but I don't mean to change the size of vbox. I really donn't know how to deal with it.